# Liaison avec « mais »

Tags: conjonctions, liaisons

Dans la phrase « Elle peut manger des crêpes, mais elle veut manger du chocolat ». Pourquoi n'y a-t-il pas de liaison entre les mots « mais » et « elle » ? En général, quand est-ce qu'il y a une liaison avec « mais » ?

Comment: La liaison est facultative, on peut la faire, mais ce n'est pas obligatoire. Pour la liste des liaisons obligatoires voir [ici](http://www.lepointdufle.net/ressources_fle/liaisons_obligatoires_liaisons_interdites.htm)

Answer (score 10):

La liaison est souvent facultative en français. Il y a certains cas où elle est obligatoire, en général lorsqu'il y a un lien fort entre les deux mots, par exemple entre un article et le nom qui suit (« les‿enfants ») ou après un pronom sujet (« ils‿ont mangé »). Il y a certains cas où elle est facultative, en général lorsque la séparation entre les mots est forte, par exemple entre un verbe et son complément. Dans beaucoup de cas, on peut la faire ou ne pas la faire. On a plus tendance à la faire en langue soutenue et moins tendance à la faire en langue familière.

Après *mais*, la liaison est facultative. Lorsque *mais* est suivi d'un adverbe qui le modifie, par exemple « mais encore » ou « mais alors », elle est très courante, mais pas obligatoire. Lorsque *mais* est suivi d'un autre mot qui n'est pas directement lié, comme dans ta phrase (« mais elle … »), on ne fait souvent pas la liaison en langue familière, mais on peut la faire (et on la fait toujours en langue très soutenue ou en poésie).

Answer (score 1):

Il y bien une liaison entre `mais` et `elle`.

D'où tiens-tu qu'il n'y en a pas ?

Comment: Dans Duolingo. j'essaye d'apprendre le français à partir de là

Comment: @gelolopez Méfie-toi de Duolingo pour la prononciation. C'est de la synthèse vocale, et pas toujours parfaite

Comment: @Evpok C'est tout de même un très bon départ pour apprendre le français.